# IsEmpty() Excel function in vba not operating as expected

Tags: vba, excel

I want create a worksheet that has a number of properties, e.g. columns that only accept number entries and columns that only accept values from drop down lists. I have created a VBA script which works almost perfectly however I have one problem I can't solve which seems to be related to the `IsEmpty()` function.

At the moment, in columns C, D and H I can only enter values form the drop down list and my error message ("Please select value from drop-down list") is thrown otherwise (including if values are pasted in). The `IsEmpty()` function call allows values to be deleted without throwing errors.

In the `Value_Columns` range, again I can only enter values and these are formatted correctly. If I delete the value in a single cell, the `IsEmpty()` function behaves normally, and the value is cleared. However, if I select a range of cells (e.g. `I5:I10`) and press delete, the following error message is thrown:

> Entry must be a number

This is in contrast to columns C, D and H, where deleting a range of cell contents throws no error message.

I can't see any reason why this behaviour appears to be inconsistent. Can anyone help?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Industry_Column As Range
Dim Proposition_Column As Range
Dim Status_Column As Range
Dim Value_Columns As Range

Set Industry_Column = Range("C5:C500")
Set Proposition_Column = Range("D5:D500")
Set Status_Column = Range("H5:H500")
Set Value_Columns = Range("I5:W500")

If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Industry_Column) Is Nothing Then

        If IsError(Application.Match(Target, Worksheets("Drop Down Lists").Range("A2:A6"), 0)) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "ERROR - Please select value from drop-down list"
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, Proposition_Column) Is Nothing Then

        If IsError(Application.Match(Target, Worksheets("Drop Down Lists").Range("C2:C6"), 0)) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "ERROR - Please select value from drop-down list"
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, Status_Column) Is Nothing Then

        If IsError(Application.Match(Target, Worksheets("Drop Down Lists").Range("E2:E6"), 0)) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "ERROR - Please select value from drop-down list"
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, Value_Columns) Is Nothing Then

        If Not IsNumeric(Target) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "ERROR - Entry must be a number"
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        Else

            Target.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-#,##0.00 "

        End If

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on the definition of IsEmpty() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx it indicate it work on an expression

When you do `If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then` VBA implicitly cast it `If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then` and Range.Value is an expression. So a standalone range can be considered an expression.

But in your case, the implicit cast to expression don't work. You'll have to create a fonction that look if all cells are empty.

Implement and replace your `IsEmpty()` by the following `IsRangeEmpty()` and it will work

```
' Return if a range is empty
Private Function IsRangeEmpty(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    ' for each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        ' if a cell is not empty
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            ' return "not empty"
            IsRangeEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ' Here all cells are empty
    IsRangeEmpty = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation! I have tried your function and that works perfectly.